# Performance penalty of getSerializedSize() in Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, performance, protocol-buffers

Is there a performance penalty for calling `getSerializedSize()` on a GPB message before serializing the message with `writeTo(OutputStream)`?

I need to be able to know the size of a message before writing it to an output stream.

I'm using GPB on Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no performance penalty. From the second message of [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/070cc0f632228195?pli=1) on the Protobuf mailing list:

> You can call getSerializedSize() to find out the message size ahead of time.
>    Note that calling this doesn't actually waste any time since the result is
>   cached, and it would have to be called during serialization anyway.